# Echoing result of multiple shell command outputs in bash

Tags: bash, shell, variables, scripting, echo

I am trying to return the result of multiple commands into a single output line. The issue is it seems to output the commands on top of each other, only when the variables are commands.

Example 1:

```
Provider=$(adb shell getprop gsm.operator.alpha)
Model=$(adb shell getprop ro.product.model)
pM=$Provider $Model
echo $pM + " is connected"
```

Output: is connected
Expected: T-Mobile Nexus 5 is connected

```
echo
a='hello '
b='world'
c=$a$b
echo $c " its pretty outside."
```

Works as expected, output: hello world its pretty outside.

I appreciated any assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lines in the output of `adb shell` commands are terminated by `\r\n`, so you have to remove the `\r`.
There are many ways of doing it, here you are one (and some other corrections):

```
Provider=$(adb shell getprop gsm.operator.alpha | tr -d \\r)
Model=$(adb shell getprop ro.product.model | tr -d \\r)
pM="$Provider $Model"
echo $pM " is connected"
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the third line to

```
pM="$Provider $Model"
```